# codeigniter4 captchav2 input not being stored in mysql database

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm trying to insert data into a contact form which should verify my captchav2 test and insert data into the database, but its not
redirecting.
The submit button works and redirects me to the captcha test and after doing the captcha test its not redirecting to the success page.
I'm using web tutorials and
I changed the code a bit but still not working.I'm using captcha v2 and put the site key and secret key in my env file.

Used this tutorial
https://www.tutsmake.com/codeigniter-4-google-recaptcha-v2-example/

and this one
https://makitweb.com/add-google-recaptcha-v2-to-form-in-codeigniter-4/

CaptchaController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\CaptchaModel;
class CaptchaController extends BaseController{

public function index() {
  
helper(['form', 'reCaptcha']);
$data = [];
return view('captcha');
}

public function submitcontactus() {
helper(['form']);
$rules = [
'name' => 'required|min_length[3]',
'email' => 'required|valid_email',
'subject' => 'required|max_length[20]',
'message' => 'required|max_length[300]',
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
];

if($this->validate($rules)){
$formModel = new CaptchaModel();
$data = [
'name' => $this->request->getVar('name'),
'email'  => $this->request->getVar('email'),
'subject'  => $this->request->getVar('subject'),
'message'  => $this->request->getVar('message'),
'g-recaptcha-response' => $this->request->getVar('g-recaptcha-response'),            

];

$recaptchaResponse = trim($this->request->getVar('g-recaptcha-response'));

//$userIp=$this->request->ip_address();

$secret='xxxxxxxxxxxx';


$credential = array(
'secret' => $secret,
'response' => $this->request->getVar('g-recaptcha-response')
);

$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($credential));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);

$status= json_decode($response, true);

if($status['success']){
$model->save($data);
$session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Form has been successfully submitted');
}else{
$session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Something goes to wrong');
}

return redirect()->to('/captcha/success');
}
}
}
```

views/captcha.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Add Google reCAPTCHA v2 to form in CodeIgniter 4</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&r ender=explicit" 
     async defer>
 </script>

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- reCAPTCHA JS-->
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var onloadCallback = function() {
alert("grecaptcha is ready!");
};
</script>

div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mt-5" style="margin: 0 auto;">

<?php

if(session()->has('message')){
?>
<div class="alert <?= session()->getFlashdata('alert-class') ?>">
<?= session()->getFlashdata('message') ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<h2 class="mb-4">Contact US</h2>

<?php $validation = \Config\Services::validation(); ?>

<form method="post" action="           <?=site_url('CaptchaController/submitcontactus')?>">

<?= csrf_field(); ?>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:              </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="<?= old('name') ?>">
                           </div>


<?php if( $validation->getError('name') ) {?>
<div class='text-danger mt-2'>
* <?= $validation->getError('name'); ?>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" value="<?= old('email') ?>">
</div>

<!-- Error -->
<?php if( $validation->getError('email') ) {?>
<div class='text-danger mt-2'>
* <?= $validation->getError('email'); ?>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Subject:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject" name="subject" value="<?= old('subject') ?>" >
</div>


<?php if( $validation->getError('subject') ) {?>
<div class='text-danger mt-2'>
* <?= $validation->getError('subject'); ?>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"><?= old('message') ?></textarea>
</div>

<!-- Error -->
<?php if( $validation->getError('message') ) {?>
<div class='text-danger mt-2'>
* <?= $validation->getError('message'); ?>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxx"></div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" id="send_form" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>








<?php if( $validation->getError('g-recaptcha-response') ) {?>
<div class='text-danger mt-2'>
* <?= $validation->getError('g-recaptcha-response'); ?>
</div>
<?php }?>

</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

model.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class CaptchaModel extends Model
{
protected $table = 'form_table';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message', 'g-recaptcha-response' ];


}
```

Config/CaptchaValidation.php

```
<?php
namespace Config;

class CaptchaValidation{
                      
public function verifyrecaptchaV2(string $str, ?string &$error = null): bool
{
$secretkey = getenv('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHAV2_SECRETKEY');

if(($str) && !empty($str)) {

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretkey."&response=".$str."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$responseData = json_decode($response);
$score = 0.6; // 0 - 1
if($responseData->success && $responseData->score > $score) { // Verified
return true;
}
}

$error = "Invalid captcha";

return false;
}

}
```

db.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`message` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`g-recaptcha-response` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```